# how to remove storyboard warning: unsupported configuratin Prototype collection view cells must have reuse identifiers

Tags: xcode, swift

I am using xcode 6.1
when running the app it show warning
1 : storyboard warning: unsupported configuration Prototype collection view cells must have reuse identifiers
2 :Main.storyboard Showing first 200 warnings only

in my main view i have a collectionView inside this collectionView i have 64 collection reusable View

my app is running fine but i want to remove this warning
please help me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just give them reuseIdentifier as `Cell` for remove that warning.

You can find it when you click on collectionView cell in Attributes Inspector window. Like shown in this Image.

[image]

Comment: i have 64 collectionView cell so give all 64 collectionView cell same name?

Comment: yea thats the only way to remove this warning but why you want to remove that? because this warning may not cause any problem if you don't need any cell Identifier.

Comment: FYI, in my case even after adding the id, the warning was still showing even after build, clean etc... I had to restart XCode to finally have it go away.